# Grep - extracting lines from a file based on patterns in another file

Tags: unix, grep, extract

The question title is not perfectly accurate, but I was not sure how to phrase it so please feel free to improve the title.

I have one file with two columns that represent gene pairs, like this:

```
scign012208 scigt009306
scign019190 scigt021712
scign000207 scigt021506
scign011139 scigt008461
scign018733 scigt003814
```

And I have another file which contains expression information on one line for each gene, but in a different order than the pairs above:

```
scign012208 92.2080327275079    134.028976718368    161.049844993173
scigt021506 271.448068344812    244.144367035135    352.78889225294
scign011139 0   0   1.22007458328161
scigt021712 69.3835869760283    70.7270589739666    65.015475611569
scigt009306 91.2941933895109    159.815950566175    221.69211356076
scign018733 1.35600048128688    0   0
scigt021506 271.448068344812    244.144367035135    352.78889225294
scign019190 1.35600048128688    5.86988219204531    3.66022374984483
```

I want to extract lines matching the gene names above and keep the two pairs on separate lines following each other, like this:

```
scign012208 92.2080327275079    134.028976718368    161.049844993173
scigt009306 91.2941933895109    159.815950566175    221.69211356076
scign019190 1.35600048128688    5.86988219204531    3.66022374984483
scigt021712 69.3835869760283    70.7270589739666    65.015475611569
```

I tried using grep -E and putting "|" between the two columns in the first file, but how to maintain the right order?

Comment: What do you mean "the right order? Do you mean that the pairs from the first file need to be collated as sequential lines in the output (even though they may not be sequential lines in the input)?

Comment: Please show the desired results.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to show the desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite simple with `xargs`.

```
cat file1 | xargs -n 1 -I % grep % file2
```

The key here is `xargs -n 1`. It limits `xargs` to taking only one word at a time, instead of reading the file line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, but suspect this is close to the answer!

```
awk 'FNR==NR{p[++i]=$1;p[++i]=$2;next} {e[$1]=$0} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++)print e[p[j]]}' pairs.txt expressions.txt
```

Ok, I read in the file `pairs.txt` and save the items in there in an array `p[]`, so `p[1]` gets `scign012208`, `p[2]` gets `scigt009306`.

Then, I read in the file `expressions.txt` and save the expressions in array `e[]`, so `e[scign012208]` gets `scign012208 92.2080327275079    134.028976718368    161.049844993173` and so on.

Then, at the end, I whizz through the elements of `p[]` in order, and pick up the matching stuff from `e[]`.

Oh, sorry, I just saw I was supposed to do it with `grep`, you can do this I suppose - but it will be slow if `expressions.txt` is a big file:

```
while read a b; do grep "$a" expressions.txt; grep "$b" expressions.txt; done < pairs.txt
```